# Grouping sub query in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ClientID  Amount     flag
MMC          600     1  
MMC          700     1
FDN          800     1
FDN          350     2
FDN          700     1
```

Using sql server,Below query I am getting 2 rows fro FDN. I just would like to combine Client values in one row.
Output should be like

```
Client  gtcount, totalAmountGreaterThan500  lscount,AmountLessThan500
MMC  2  1300               0        0
FDN  2      1500               1        350
```

```
SELECT 
    f.ClientID,f.flag,    
case when flag = 1 then count(*) END as gtcount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN Amount END) AS totalAmountGreaterThan500,
case when flag = 2 then count(*) END as lscount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN Amount END) AS AmountLessThan500,
from
    ( select ClientID, Amount,flag from #myTable)f
group by ClientID,f.flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ClientID,    
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gtcount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS totalAmountGreaterThan500,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lscount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS AmountLessThan500
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY ClientID
```

Output:

```
| CLIENTID | GTCOUNT | TOTALAMOUNTGREATERTHAN500 | LSCOUNT | AMOUNTLESSTHAN500 |
|----------|---------|---------------------------|---------|-------------------|
|      FDN |       2 |                      1500 |       1 |               350 |
|      MMC |       2 |                      1300 |       0 |                 0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c75/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your desired output is off -- there aren't any `mmc` records less than 500.  You can accomplish this using `sum` with `case` for each of your fields, removing `flag` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT 
    ClientID,    
    SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 1 END) as gtcount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN Amount END) AS totalAmountGreaterThan500,
    SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 2 THEN 1 END) as ltcount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 2 THEN Amount END) AS AmountLessThan500
from myTable
group by ClientID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3da6e/9)

On a different note, not sure why you need the `Flag` field.  If it's just being used to denote less than records, just add the logic to the query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Amount <= 500 Then ...)
```

Comment: @MeteAgar -- no worries, glad we could help!